# can't init collection using xml configuration in autofac c#

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm trying to initialize a collection using autofac's  xml configuration but cannot seem to find out how it's done.

There is very little documentation regarding the structure of the nested components of the xml file in the autofac repo.

Anyone ever managed it?

Comment: Could you post a little example? also maybe in what way you would do it via code?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: [link](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=319)

But this solution doesn't support injecting complex objects too smoothly.